# Find all points where $f(x)$ fails to be differentiable. Justify your answer

Tags: limits, derivatives, continuity

Find all points where  $f(x)$  fails to be differentiable. Justify your answer

$$f(x) = |x| - 1$$

I am confused with continuity of it and cannot turn it into piecewise function and finding the limit of it at the points by piecewise function 
Sorry for bad explanation :-(

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)=x-1\forall x>0$ and $f(x)=-x-1\forall x<0$

now clearly  $f$ is not differentiable at $x=0$

$\lim_{x\uparrow 0} {f(x)-f(0)\over x-0}=\lim_{x\uparrow 0}{-x-1-(-1)\over x-0}=-1$

$\lim_{x\downarrow 0} {f(x)-f(0)\over x-0}=\lim_{x\downarrow 0}{x-1-(-1)\over x-0}=1$

$\lim_{x\uparrow 0}$ means $x<0$ and $x$ is tending to $0$ from the left

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim \limits_{x \to 0^-}f(x) \ne \lim \limits_{x \to 0^+}f(x)$$

So it's not differentiable at $x=0$.

Answer (score 0):

The function is continuous at every point in $\mathbb R$. But it is not differentiable only at $0$.

Comment: Can you please elaborate the continuity and correct me if I am wrong that mod functions are continuous all the time but here - 1 is out side mod

Comment: Just think about the graph of the function $\vert x \vert-1$. It will be similar to that of $\vert x\vert$. This is symmetric about $Y-$axis and vanishes at -1.

Comment: @Anupam You should edit a better explanation into your question (such as the one you have just given). Even if you just leave a hint or a skeleton proof...